# How many permutations of the word TOMORROW can be made if the O's can't be together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification

I'm trying to answer this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219669/how-many-ways-can-the-letters-of-the-word-tomorrow-be-arranged-if-the-os-cant-b). This is my attempt of solution:

- First we distiguish the O's and R's, then we have the word: $TO_1MO_2R_1R_2O_3W$.
- We have $8!-7!\cdot3!-6!\cdot 3!$ different permutations of this word such that the O's aren't together. In fact, if two O's are together such as $TO_1O_2MO_3R_1R_2W$, then we have $7!\cdot3!$ permutations (the double O is viewed as a single letter). If the three O's are together such as $TO_1O_2O_3MR_1R_2W$, then we have $6!\cdot 3!$ permutations (the triple O is viewed as a single letter). Thus we subtract the total permutation $8!$ by $7!\cdot3!$ and $6!\cdot 3!$.
- divide everything by $3!\cdot2!$ to handle with the repetitions.
- The answer is $\frac{8!-7!\cdot3!-6!\cdot 3!}{3!\cdot2!}=480$ which is different than André Nicholas' answer.

  I would like to know why I'm wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain how did you get second step? Also why don't just count count total words and subtract those in which O's are togethor?

Comment: Can you explain $8!-7!\cdot3!-6!\cdot 3!$

Comment: If each of the letters were different, the answer would clearly be $8!$ (8 letters). But we can order the 3 O's in $3!=2$ different ways, and the 2 R's in $2!=2$ ways, giving $\frac{8!}{2!3!}=3360$ ways, ignoring the fact that the O's cannot be together.

Comment: @trueblueanil see my edit please

Comment: @TaylorTed see my edit please

Comment: @AnonymousPi yes I know, but I want to handle with the letter repetitions (the O's and R's) after removing the words with the O's together.

Comment: @user75086 Then I'll give you a hint: In how many ways can you choose the places where the three Os go without them being together? This can be counted very easy, actually. After that, mutliply the result by $3!$ to account for the T, M, and W (the Rs go in in just one way afterwards) and you're done.

Comment: I think answer should be $1740$

Comment: @user75086 The permutations for two O's togethor also constitutes of having 3 O's togethor. You have not fixed any letter between two O's and single O left over

Comment: @AnonymousPi I found 35 places where the three O's go without them being together. I don't know where I'm wrong. I didn't get the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are double counting, as, for example, "TOOOMRRW" is included in both your double-O case and your triple-O case. This explains why your answer is smaller than Andre's.

Consider counting your solution a little differently. We need to find the number of double-O cases that are not triple-O cases. As you said, there are 7 positions to put the double-O, since we can treat it as one letter. However, we need to make sure that the third O does not touch this double-O letter. We have to case this even further: if the double-O is on an edge, then there are 5 possible positions for the third O; otherwise, it only has 4 possible positions. Given the positions of the double-O and the third O, the remaining 5 letters can be placed in any order. Further, the 3 O's can also be shuffled.

Thus, our total for the double-O case is $(5+5+4+4+4+4+4)*5!*3!$. Our final solution is $(8! - 6!*3! - (5+5+4+4+4+4+4)*5!*3!)/(3!*2!) = 1200$.

Comment: Thank you! It was exactly I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If the question was # of permutations in which all 3 O's are not together, you could easily use *Total ways - ways with all O's together*

This "subtraction" method  also works well for "none of the O's together" if there were only 2 O's

For more than 2 O's, it becomes quite complex, and is best avoided. What you have not considered is that when 2 O's are together, it could be *any two* of the 3 O's, and that the "solo" O has a number of positions where it can be placed, which must be *apart* from the "double O's.

But why go into all that ? Use Andre's method !