# In how many ways can the letters of the word ALGEBRA be rearranged?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways, can the letters of the word ALGEBRA be rearranged with condition: the two As never appear next to each other.

The way I think of a solution is: total number of permutations of the word ALGEBRA (accounting for the two As) - the total number of permutations of the word ALGEBRA where the two As **do** occur together.

The answer stood out to be 1800. Can someone confirm this?

EDIT: elaborated solution -
1. total number of permutations of the word ALGEBRA with the two As accounted for: 7! / 2! = 2520
2. total number of permutations of the word ALGEBRA with the two As **always** occurring together("AA",L,G,E,B,R being the distinct elements): 6! = 720

hence answer is 1 minus 2 i.e 1800.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to show us just how you came up with that answer.

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: This site is full of similar questions, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219669/how-many-ways-can-the-letters-of-the-word-tomorrow-be-arranged-if-the-os-cant-b?rq=1) and the related questions. It might be useful to compare with them to obtain confirmation yourself (you don't need confirmation by others, you want to see it yourself).